# Error when attempting to load a file into hdfs

Tags: java, hive, hdfs

This java method, which loads a file into HDFS, has been working for me, but now, there seems to be a security related error that is preventing the file from being loaded properly.

```
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     InputStream inputStream =
     new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localFilepath));
     FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(HdfsURI), conf);
     OutputStream outputStream = hdfs.create(new Path(fileDestination));
```

The error is thrown when attempting to get the location of the file in hdfs on the fourth line above:

```
    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem cannot access its superinterface org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.TokenAspect$TokenManagementDelegator
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:3268)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3313)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3352)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
at TestMethods.loadFile(LoadFile.java:157)
```

Comment: This can help :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880009/error-through-remote-spark-job-java-lang-illegalaccesserror-class-org-apache-h